# Is it safe to swap a fused IEC cable to non-fused when in another country?

Tags: appliances

I have recently moved from Singapore to New Zealand and have brought a number of eletrical applicances with me e.g. computer, ricecooker, router, etc.

Since the voltages are the same (currently using travel adaptors with a power board), I was assuming that as long as the applicance doesn't draw over 10A, then I could just swap out the fused Brittish IEC C8 & C14 cables with local non-fused ones. However I noticed that the rice cooker (C13/14 with a 10A fuse) has a sticker on it *warning: do not use power cord from other applicances*, so it got me wondering if it was infact safe or if they were just being overly cautious (or wanting you to pay for their expensive replacement cord).

Can I safely swap these IEC cables over?

Comment: Most consumer warnings are to absolve the manufacturer of blame; if it starts a fire (not necessarily that it *will*) then clearly it was *your* fault.

Answer (score 2):

Perfectly fine as long as the cable itself is the right rating.

Many cheap IEC cables, although the connectors are rated at 10A, the cable itself is a lower rating (because it's cheaper), such as 5A (why use 10A cable on an appliance that only draws a couple of amps?).

That's why you shouldn't use a cable from something else on the rice cooker, as it would need more than a generic cheap cable can safely handle.

(note: the UK electrical regulations are fixated on fuses. There's fuses everywhere, even when they're really not needed. In a typical circuit you'd have the MCB in the CU, the 13A in the 4-way strip's plug, the 13A a foot away in the 4-way itself, then another fuse (say 5A) 6 inches further away in the appliance plug, then another smaller one at the appliance entry... that's 5 fuses in a single power feed!!!)